# Android Recyclerview stagger animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

Which Android API is the best to make a stagger entrance animation like explained in the Material guidelines?

Interestingly I see that the Y transition of each item is different, based on its position.

This is the desired animation:

https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1Bc9xpqVSj0cRTtbXLGhDdtWi_OUHIQ11%2F04-staggering-vertical.mp4